# How to deal with simulation/measurement discrepancies of simple RF circuits (e.g. matching) without access to expensive equipment?

Tags: pcb, rf, impedance-matching, high-frequency, high-speed

Designing a circuit (PCB) operating at low frequencies is fairly straight forward. However, my design includes a simple RF frontend. The frontend consists of usual componenents on a PCB (SMA connector, transmission lines, L-match, RF switches) and a few RF diodes to convert voltages to DC (where further low frequency processing happens).
This node after the diode is the one node that I can verify/measure with my hobbyist equipment (multimeter/scope). What I measure is clearly way off from my simulations (LTspice).

I am concerned about the L-match: In LTspice, I tried to somewhat capture main parasitic sources [*], then simulate input impedance and design proper L-match (L and C) at 900 MHz which gives me good S11 in the LTspice simulation.

The measurements are totally off. Now what I started to do is to first solder different inductor values for the L-match and see which one gives the highest voltage level after the diodes. Afterwards, I solder different capacitor values and pick the one which gives highest voltage/largest bandwidth. The C value is so small (~1's of pF) that equivalently I can just leave it out.

I destroyed already a board because of all the soldering/desoldering (pad got loose from PCB).

Is this really all I can do under these assumptions?
Is it really fair to say that LTspice simulations are completely useless for RF -- even to first order?

[*]: I add a few pF's to packaging (e.g. RF switches) and PCB traces, model capacitors with proper ESL and ESR and model inductors with proper R and C based on resonance frequency.

PS: Did I mention hobbyist setting? I do *not* have access to a VNA or TDR.

Comment: I would like to point out that there are some cheap hobby-aimed VNAs on the market now. Sure, they don't offer the 140 dB dynamic range the half-a-million-buck units from the three big names offer, but for a hobby application they can be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks. It's not directly an answer to my question but do you have a recommendation? Furthermore, my L-match is after two RF switches and a transmission line (in front of the diodes). A VNA would likely show me that I have an impedance mismatch but not how to pick the L/C value. (for *that* only a TDR might help which would localize where impedance mismatch occurs)

Comment: Can you add a schematic, and/or photo, and/or layout of the RF front end?